# How do I find the area bounded by two curves that never intersect on the interval $[2, +\infty]$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, area

So, I know how to find the area between curves when they are bounded, but what do I do here when they are unbounded. I have learned about improper integrals, but I am not sure how I can use them here. 
I have already done some work, but I'm not sure if it is correct or if I am going in the right direction.

Can anyone suggest how I can start?

[image]

Comment: You end up dealing with an improper integral. Combine the natural logs before considering infinity as the upper limit

Answer (score 2):

It is the integral

$$\int_2^\infty\left(\frac2{x-1}-\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\right)\,dx=\left.\lim_{b\to\infty}\left[2\log(x-1)-\log(x^2+1)\right]\right|_2^b=$$

$$\left.\lim_{b\to\infty}\log\frac{(x-1)^2}{x^2+1}\right|_2^b=\lim_{b\to\infty}\left[\log\frac{(b-1)^2}{b^2+1}-\log\frac15\right]=\log1-\log\frac15=\log5$$

Comment: Thank you! When you put log, did you mean natural log(ln)?

Comment: @P1081 Yes, that's right.

Comment: question: How did you get log of 1/2. Shouldn't it be log of 1/5?

Comment: @P1081 You're completely right. That was a mistake, corrected. Thanks.